# Change listening port for Tang

Tags: server, 20.04, encryption

I am trying to change the port on Tang from 80 to 7500 I am running Ubuntu 20.04. Pretty much everything I have come up with through googling has been geared for RedHat (and it works on RedHat based systems) These are the steps I have taken:
`sudo apt install tang jose` (installing jose is the only difference in what is installed from various instructions)

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/tangd.socket.d
sudo vim /etc/systemd/systemd/tangd.socket.d/port.conf
```

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=7500
```

save file

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable tangd.socket
```

I open the 7500 port using `ufw allow 7500/tcp` and reload the firewall
I generate a key using the following:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tangd-keygen /var/db/tang
```

which generates randomhash.jwk in /var/db/tang
however when i try to view keys

```
sudo tang-show-keys 7500
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7500: Connection refused
```

(though this previously worked using the default install port)

```
sudo systemctl show tangd.socket -p Listen
Listen=[::]:7500 (Stream)
```

However, netstat does not show a port listening on 7500
Client servers return Unable to fetch advertisement
I am sure i left out something that is needed to trouble shoot this, just let me know.

```
dpkg -l |grep tang

ii  tang                                  7-1ubuntu0.1                          amd64        network-based cryptographic binding server

VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```